# Terminology: algebras, sigma-algebras, complete algebras...

Tags: boolean-algebra

There are 2 things which create a lot of confusion in my mind.

---

1) I know that every sigma-algebra is an algebra. But not every algebra is a sigma-algebra. Put differently, it seems that sigma-algebras are subsets of algebras (?).

On the other hand, a sigma-algebra is an algebra complemented to include countably infinite operations (Wikipedia). Hence, it seems that algebras are subsets of sigma-algebras (?).

Could anybody please clarify? I just can't get my head around.

---

2) Also, it is true to say that:

finite algebra $\subset$ sigma-algebra (i.e. countably complete algebra) $\subset$ complete algebras?

If so, what do we mean by an arbitrary algebra?

---

Thank you very much.

Comment: If I understood your question, you are confusing algebras (and sigma algebras) with their elements.

Answer (score 2):

An algebra, in this context, an algebra of sets, is a family of subsets of some $X$ which includes $X$, closed under complements and *finite* unions. For example consider all the finite and co-finite sets of natural numbers.

A $\sigma$-algebra is an algebra which is closed under countable unions. So we require not only that $A\cup B$ is in the algebra whenever $A$ and $B$ are, but if for every $n\in\Bbb N$ $A_n$ is in the algebra, then $\bigcup_{n\in\Bbb N} A_n$ is in the algebra. The example of finite and co-finite sets doesn't work anymore. Consider $A_n=\{2n\}$, then $\bigcup_{n\in\Bbb N}A_n$ is the set of even integers, which is neither finite nor co-finite.

We can have algebras whose "completion" is even larger, we can require unions of $\aleph_1$ elements from algebra to be in the algebra, or we can require that *any* union of elements is an element. The latter are known as complete Boolean algebras, and for example $\mathcal P(X)$ is a complete Boolean algebra for any $X$ (note that the union of any collection of subsets of $X$ is still a subset of $X$).

So we have that $\sf\text{algebra}\supsetneq\sigma\text{-algebra}\supsetneq\text{complete algebra}$, and not as you have written where the inclusions go the other way around.

Comment: Your answer really helped me understand this point. However, there is an example I can't wrap my head around. Let $X =\mathbb{R}$. Define an algebra $\mathcal{A}$ which consists of sets in the form $$ \cup_{i = 1}^k (a_i, b_i]$$ where $-\infty \leq a_i < b_i \leq \infty$. The book says that this is an algebra of sets, but not quite a $\sigma$ algebra

Comment: Yes, it's an algebra. To see why, note that it's clearly closed under finite unions and the complement of $(a_i,b_i]$ is $(-\infty,a_i]\cup(b_i,\infty]$. But it's not a $\sigma$-algebra since it does not contain any open interval (except $\Bbb R$ itself) but $(0,1)$ is the intersection of $(0,1+\frac1n]$. Also, in the presentation you give, you need to explicitly add $\varnothing$; you can fix that by allowing $a_i\leq b_i$ rather than $a_i<b_i$ and thus generate the empty set as $(0,0]$.

Answer (score 0):

1)

a. Humans who wear hats are subset of all humans.
b. To turn a human into a hat-human, put a hat on him/her.

Arbitrary algebra = arbitrary human.

2)

Humans $\supset$ Hat-humans $\supset$ The Pope

But if you look at Popes, set of Humans (as restricted to Popes) $=$ set of Hat-Humans

Answer (score 0):

Let $X$ be a set. A $\sigma$-algebra of subsets of $X$ is a family $\Sigma$ of subsets of $X$ which contains the empty set and which is closed under the formation of complements and countable unions, that is:

(i) $\emptyset\in\Sigma$;

(ii) If $E\in\Sigma$ then $-E\in\Sigma$;

(iii) If $E_0,E_1,...,E_n,...\in\Sigma$ then $\bigcup_{n=0}^{+\infty} E_n\in\Sigma$.

Now, if a family of subsets of $X$ is closed under the formation of countable unions, then it is closed under the formation of finite unions.

Indeed, set $E=E_0$ and $F=E_n$ for every $n\geq 1$. Then $E\cup F=\bigcup_{n=0}^{+\infty} E_n\in\Sigma$.

Hence, if $\Sigma$ is a $\sigma$-algebra then it is an algebra, that is to say, $\sigma$-algebras $\subset$ algebras.